# Cannot assign a vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I cannot use =operator in the below code, as I am getting compiller error. I cannot understand what is wrong.

```
int CProcessData::calculateMidPoints(const std::vector<double>& xv, const std::vector<double>& yv)
{
    if((0 == xv.size()) || (0 == yv.size()))
        return 1;

    std::vector<double>::iterator it;

    for (it = xv.begin(); it < xv.end(); it++)
    {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
../src/CProcessData.cpp: In member function ‘int CProcessData::calculateMidPoints(const std::vector<double>&, const std::vector<double>&)’:
../src/CProcessData.cpp:44:9: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<double>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >}’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const double*, std::vector<double> >’)
```

I would aprichiate all help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xv` is a `const` reference, meaning only `const` member functions can be called in it. The `const` overload of `std::vector<double>::begin()` returns a `const_iterator`, and that cannot be used to construct an `iterator` because it would break const-coreectness.

So you need

```
std::vector<double>::const_iterator it;
```

Note that since C++11 you have other alternatives:

```
for (auto it = xv.begin(); it < xv.end(); it++)
```

or, if you're iterating over all elements, a range-based loop might be better:

```
for (auto x: xv) { ... // x is a copy

for (auto& x: xv) { ... // x is a reference
```

Comment: this is correct.  if you have c++11, it might be nicer to just write `for (auto it = xv.begin(); it < xv.end(); it++)` and remove the declaration beforehand.

Comment: I am using c++11, the auto fixed the problem. Also I have realised the refferences cannot be consts as I will modify them. Thank you.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło You should post a separate question.